# Only 5 edits a day allowed

Tags: support, editing

Can't find this rule that I just encountered when editing *my own* questions, to include 1 extra tag that just got created, listed anywhere, but am guessing that someone will find it.

But I digress.. Why (I have found the discussions about minor edits, which I think is a decent idea in order to prevent the potentially insane bumping I don't care for in this case, to discuss further)?

P.S Is there a literal 24 hour timer, or is it somewhat fuzzy?

Answer (score 5):

It's explained on the [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), in [Why can't someone edit more than five of his/her own posts per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165885/why-cant-someone-edit-more-than-five-of-his-her-own-posts-per-day). It's to prevent the case where a user gets mad and tries to vandalize all their own posts before leaving the site. The site stops you from editing further, and moderators are alerted to make sure that the edits aren't destroying the posts.

Comment: Of course. I find it hard to figure out where rules that apply to all/most/a subset/etc of sites reside. Pity there isn't some othrr coding that can be done to address this single issue, rather than a blanket rule that affect legitimate edits by ?99%? of the rest of us... Something like rolling back x number of edits, or putting them in a review queue if a user goes inactive for a time/deletes their account/etc.

Comment: @user66001 We could always roll them back, but that's a lot of work if the user goes and destroys hundreds of posts. The problem is there are few valid reasons to be editing dozens of your posts at once; adding a new tag is one of the only cases I can think of

Comment: Sorry, was suggesting the roll backs could be automated. Anyways, if this is [tag:status-bydesign], do I have to keep these questions open for a full 24 hours (I use tabs to remind me to do things).?